# Nativescript: Socket connection timed out

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am on Mac and I want to run my app on a USB-C connected Android device.

My first step is always to remove node_modules, hooks and platforms folders, aswell as package.lock.json file. 
After that I run `tns build android`.
Once the build is completed I either run `tns run android` or start the application via nativescript sidekick.

But it always ends like this now:

> Project successfully built.
>   Installing on device 5B24000362...
>   Successfully installed on device with identifier '5B24000362'.
>   Unable to apply changes on device: 5B24000362. Error is: Socket connection timed out..

Since I had this error already 2 days ago and could not continue working on the App, I updated all nativescript and angular dependencies following [this upgrade instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions).
After that update, the app worked again.
But now after a few hours I get the same error again (same app).
I even pushed the app to a git repository after it worked, and recloned it now, does not work.

Comment: Any news on this? I am also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: update nativescript-firebase

Comment: Did it work for you? Maybe you should create an update so future readers will know. :) I will it as well.

Comment: yes, problem is gone since i updated the firebase plugin.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! :)

Comment: Updating the `nativescript-plugin-firebase` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `nativescript-plugin-firebase` installed. Just update it with:
`$ tns plugin update nativescript-plugin-firebase`

Comment: @SephReed, tns plugin update nativescript-plugin-firebase

Comment: I don't have this nativescript-plugin-firebase what to do?

Comment: i created a project with Hello World template and getting the same error. No nativescript-plugin-firebase plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. Interestingly, in my case, it was because the emulated device did not have enough storage to install the app. As soon as I deleted some other builds off of it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest NativeScript tooling, not only the dependencies. You can install the latest CLI by executing `npm i -g nativescript`.

If the application is not started at all, you can check [this answer](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3818#issuecomment-428644265) to a similar issue in NativeScript CLI GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working by removing admob from node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\include.gradle

Line to take out:

Comment: I think you forgot something.